# I try to login with Microsoft account and it's giving this error message "a database operation failed while processing the request."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, .net-core

i am try to login with Microsoft Authentication in .net core application but it's giving me error Like
**a database operation failed while processing the request**
 i am getting this error when i am try to execute below code

```
enter code here

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostConfirmationAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            // GetAsync the information about the user from the external login provider

            var fname = Request.Form["Input.FirstName"].ToList().First();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "FirstName Name is Required.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var Lname = Request.Form["Input.LastName"].ToList().First();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Lname))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "LastName Name is Required.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            var pNumber = Request.Form["Input.PhoneNumber"].ToList().First();
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information during confirmation.";
                return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }

            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
                //Todo: set all required fields
                var user = new User { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email,FirstName= fname, LastName=Lname,PhoneNumber=pNumber,IsActive=true };
                var searchKey = Input.Email.Split("@").Last();
                var organization = _userRepository.SearchOrganization(searchKey);
                if (organization != null)
                    user.OrganizationId = organization.Id;
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                //Todo: Set Registered role
                //Todo: Detect and assign organization
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SmartRole.RegisteredUser).Wait();
                        _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SmartRole.Anonymous).Wait();
                    user.IsAdmin =
                                   _signInManager.UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator").Result;
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        _logger.LogInformation("User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            //}

            LoginProvider = info.LoginProvider;
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return Page();
        }
```

i am try to compare some code with database that time i am getting this error

```
 public Model.Organization SearchOrganization(string searchKey)
        {
            return DbContext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(x =>x.URL.Equals(searchKey,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
```

Comment: is there any more detail to that error message?

Comment: @scgough  no this is only error i am getting when i am try to login

Comment: how does this issue related to Microsoft account login ? That seems EF related issues .

Comment: because i am try to external login authentication  like Microsoft  login

Comment: @NanYu  now plz check my code again i am try to give you more information